# Django form returns form.is_valid False

Tags: django, forms

This must be kind of basic issue but I am very new in Djnago and trying to learn how the forms work. I have looked in different sites and forums but I haven't managed to understand what I am doing wrong.

This is my form:

```
class UploadCSVForm(forms.Form):
   csv_file = forms.FileField()
```

Its a very simple form used in order to upload a CSV file.

This is what I have in my view:

```
def layer_create(request, template='layers/layer_create.html'):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    form = UploadCSVForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    #print form.is_bound  # THIS PRINTS TRUE
    #print (request.FILES['csv']) # THIS PRINTS THE FILE IN THE MEMORY

    if form.is_valid():
        print ("valid")
    else:
        print ("not valid")
        out = {'success': False}

    return HttpResponse('test site')
```

And this is the form in my Template:

```
<form id="file-uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url "layer_create" %}">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
      <input type="file" id="file-input" name="csv" />
      <button type="submit" id="upload-button" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Using the function `is_bound` I see that there are actual data bound on the form.
And when I print: `request.FILES['csv']` I can see the name of the file uploaded in the Memory.

But I still get `form.is_valid = False` without ant errors or warnings.

Comment: you can do `print (form.errors)` to print what exactly the error is

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. Thats interesting. I get this: <ul class="errorlist"><li>csv_file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: It seems like that it finds the field empty. But I thought that this is the field where I upload my file. Any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named the field in the template `csv`, but the form is expecting it to be called `csv_file`.

Generally you should let Django output the fields in the template, which will avoid issues like this. (It will also normally prepopulate the fields when redisplaying them after errors, although this doesn't happen for file fields for browser security reasons.)

```
{{ form.csv_file }}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. What do you mean to output the fields in the template? How can I do this?